# Making an API GET request and displaying the information in HTML.

Tags: angular, typescript, api, constructor, ngfor

I have been attempting to make an API call but have had no success. I get this error message when displaying the name. Very sorry that I've pasted in three files but this is my first question here and I'm a newbie. Thanks for any help.

`Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Here is my `beers.service.ts` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BeersService {
  private beerUrl = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/';
  beers;

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getListOfBeer() {
    return this._httpClient.get(this.beerUrl).subscribe(
      res => {
         this.beers = res;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my `app.component.ts` I have a feeling the problem is with the constructor but everything I have tried has led to no success.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BeersService } from './beers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  beers;

  constructor(private _beerService: BeersService) {
    this.beers = _beerService.getListOfBeer()
  }
}
```

And finally here is my `app.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let beer of beers">
    <p>{{ beer.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `beers` is probably an Object, you need to make it an `Array` if you want to iterate over it in HTML

Comment: I understand that and have tried exporting the beers as `beers = Beers[];` or `beers = any;` or even having the get request as an observable but no luck. @xyz

Comment: Can you do a console log of beers and update your question of what you see in log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about RxJS as it is used in Angular HTTP client. Function getListOfBeers returns a Subscription, not an array of beers.

In Service

```
getListOfBeer() {
    return this._httpClient.get(this.beerUrl);
}
```

In Component

```
constructor(private _beerService: BeersService) {
    _beerService.getListOfBeer().subscribe(res => this.beers = res)
}
```

and make sure that you instantiate beers with an empty array

```
beers = []
```

Comment: Ohh, yeah!! And please don't do that in constructor

Comment: Hey dude that solved my problem! Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an uninitialized variable. When you just say `beers` or `beers:any`, it is still undefined. Which means, your template is trying to loop something that is undefined (until the API request comes back, which is a few miliseconds after you get the thing).

Preinitialize the array or show it conditionally.

## Version 1:

Preinitialize the array in `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  beers = [];
  ...
```

## Version 2

On app start, your component.beers is undefined, until the API returns. You can not loop undefined, so hide the list until then. Check out `beers.component.html`:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="beers">
    <div *ngFor="let beer of beers"><p>{{ beer.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess, If it is undefined then it shouldn't loop anyway.

Comment: But it doesn't. That's why the OP is getting the error. He would either have it defined from start, or conditionally render it.